# Do I need a Transit visa

Tags: visas

Hey I'm traveling to Canada via LAX from Australia on a non connecting flight. Do I need a visa for the USA in this case, or can I change flights without a visa

Comment: What nationality are you?

Answer (score 2):

All passengers arriving in the USA for any reason (including transit) must pass through immigration. If you would normally require a visa (or ESTA) to enter the United States, then you will also require one for transit.